# How to bind the form data to the model in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make an Edit in mvc 3

Here is the code I have

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        { 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    sea loadedSea = BskDB.loadSea(id);

                    loadedBskSeason.UpdateFrom()//Error Here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View("EditSea");
                }
            }
            return View("EditSea");
        }
```

This [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx) says that the

> "UpdateFrom" extension method to
>   automatically populate our product
>   object from the request.

But in my case it gives me a compilation error - *No extension method can be found*

In this other [article](http://forums.asp.net/p/1231619/2227810.aspx) it says that the UpdateFrom has been change to

```
loadedSea.UpdateFrom(Request.Form);

to:

BindingHelperExtensions.UpdateFrom(loadedSea, Request.Form);
```

But also this doesn't work.

Any examples on how to do bindings from a collection to a model in MVC 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ScottGu article refers to a prerelease version of MVC 1 and a lot has changed since then. You might want to look into the `TryUpdateModel` family of methods.